# How do bubbles work?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

In New Super Mario Bros. and New Super Mario Bros. U, when a character gets stuck in a bubble (by dying or by hitting a ‘panic button’), the player could get the bubble to float to another character (faster) by shaking the Wii remote, allowing that character to free the trapped character. That doesn’t seem to  work in Super Mario 3D World.

Is there a way to move the bubble or otherwise escape from the bubble sooner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing the jump button allowed me to escape the bubble when I played.